# Concavity / concavity in one direction and the cross partials

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, partial-derivative

I just have a question with regards to convexity and concavity (in one direction) in relation to its cross partial derivatives. Suppose we have a smooth function $f(x,y)$ on well defined domains. And suppose we know that the function is say globally "convex" (or concave) in one direction, say the $x$-direction. So there exists some $x_0$ such that,

$f_x(x_0, y) = 0$ for all $y$; and

$f_{xx}(x, y) \geq 0$ for all $x,y$.

Can we thus conclude something about the cross partial derivatives? Can we then say that for each $y$, the map $x \mapsto f_{xy}(x,y)$ is convex in the $x$-direction also?

Thank you so much!

PS. An example that would satisfy the above is something like $f(x,y) = x^2 \sin(y)$. But I'm just not sure whether this will generalize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f(x,y)=x^4 \sin y$ satisfies the given assumptions but $f_{xy}(x,y) = 4x^3 \cos y$ is not always convex in the $x$-direction. Indeed, $f_{xxxy}(x,y)=24x\cos y$ changes sign.

In general, convexity in direction $v$ tells you that $v^TD^2f(x,y)v\ge 0$ for all $(x,y)$. Depending on $v$, this may encode some information about mixed partials, but   not enough to determine the sign of $f_{xy}$.

Consider the following: replacing $f(x,y)$ with $f(-x,y)$ retains all properties of convexity, but changes the sign of the $xy$-derivative.

Comment: Thanks! After that posting, I soon realized that (even through a brute force definition chasing type argument) what I'd written down is nonsense. Thanks for the nice counterexample!